# Simple auto-completion function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to get a simple auto-complete function to work based off the usernames that a 3rd party app provides.

The app outputs data in this general format:

```
"{
"UserA":{"IP":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","ConnectTime":"/Date(1435769694510)/","LastAskSource":"","LastAskType":2,"Name":"UserA"},
"UserB":{"IP":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","ConnectTime":"/Date(1435769694510)/","LastAskSource":"","LastAskType":2,"Name":"UserB"},
"UserC":{"IP":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","ConnectTime":"/Date(1435769694510)/","LastAskSource":"","LastAskType":2,"Name":"UserC"}
}"
```

Now, I want to use the general auto-complete function listed below:

```
$("#chatEntryBox").autocomplete({
    source: usersOnline.Name
});
```

I have defined the array as such:

```
OnlineUsers = data.userinfo;

for (var i in OnlineUsers) {
  var user = OnlineUsers[i];
  usersOnline = $.map(OnlineUsers, function(el) { return el; })
}
```

Now, this part above works the way I would expect. I can test in the console what the values are of the array by doing `JSON.stringify(usersOnline[0].Name);`

I have looked at the documentation on the website for Jquery... I just think I am missing something or misunderstanding. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

The end goal would be typing the first few letters of the users name, and it auto-completing the rest.

Comment: As what the value return seems to be a `json` string, Try `JSON.parse(data)`  to make it and normal `object`?

Comment: Where would I locate that in my code? In the For loop?

Comment: when the data is returned to you from the service do something along the lines of var response = JSON.parse(data) where data is the data that is returned from the service. This will allow you to manipulate the json just as a normal javascript object. You would do this immediately after receiving the data wherever that is

Comment: Parsing does not work because of the extra quotes on the front and back of the json string. Its not reading it as valid. Is there a way to strip those off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle for your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/393/).

Loop to take out names from json can be as simple as this

```
var usersOnline = $.map(input, function(el) { return el.Name; })

$( "#chatEntryBox" ).autocomplete({
    source: usersOnline
});
```

Comment: I implmented what you have, but for some reason I have now am getting an issue with my script "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
I also am reading undefined when I look at the variable from console.

Comment: @FrankEdgar can you share a fiddle of your problem.
Seems ur source array u formed from json is having some problem.

Did you change array name <input> to your actual variable...may be that is causing you undefined error

Comment: This solution is correct. I was trying to pass the JSON string outside of its scope, which added a set of " " to the entire thing. If I processed it in the loop where it was generated and then passed the processed array to my autocomplete function it worked. 

Thank you sir.